# Why linking to a LIB significantly increases binary's size

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, compiler-optimization, static-linking

Lets say i have a module(DLL / EXE) which defines a certain flow with N objects, after compilation / linking, module's size is X.

If i ever decide to break down that module, into a main executable and a helper LIB file, counting exactly the N objects i described earlier, will the overall size of the executable remain the same?

I know that during linkage, the compiler decides which parts of the LIB copy into the executable, so i'd expect the overall size of the executable to be smaller or equal to the executable.

I've defined the LIB project with favor size over speed and minimum size(O1).

Just to clear things out, I've decided to implement a small HelloWorld function in the LIB(global function), and removed any references to the LIB's objects from the main executable, and executing the following command

```
#include "../LibObject/Function.h"
void main()
{
     HelloWorld();
}
```

executable's overall size has remained the size as if i'd call to original objects, howcome?

Comment: Are you asking why your executable did not get smaller when you moved some things into a static library? If so...why would it? Why would the linker be able to eliminate more code from a lib than from a plain object file?

Comment: Also, your question's title asks "why does the binary size increase", and the actual question seems to ask "why doesn't the binary size get smaller". While those aren't mutually exclusive, could you clarify?

Comment: Code that is now in the DLL will have to be linked into the EXE.  So of course the EXE can never get smaller.  Best you can hope for is that the EXE will be smaller than the *combined* size of the original EXE and DLL.

Comment: @melak47, I'd go with your second interpretation, I thought that the overall size would eventually decrease. if i to use a single global function from the library rather than the main object, it should decrease in length.

Answer (score 4):

Static libraries are in almost all regards just a collection of object modules (think of them as a `.zip` of `.obj`); there's no real difference for the linker whether you pass all your object files separately or all together in a static library (the dead functions elimination, if possible, is performed in the same way), so the fact that you see the same effect on the executable size with or without the intermediate library step is completely expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are forward declaring the class but not defining it which doesn't really make sense. If it is defined in the header files then you don't need to forward declare it. If it is a class the you are creating then just forward declaring it is not enough. You need to define the class. You seem to have straddled the fence.

```
    namespace Ramy{
    namespace TEST {
        namespace standard{
            class StandardAnalyzer;
        }
    }
}
```

is the forward declaration. It just tells the compiler that the class exists, it doesn't tell the compiler anything about it. The compiler needs a class definition.

So, is it a class that is defined in the Ramy libraries or is it a class you are creating yourself? Depends on your answer.

This is the reason because when you link a program with a library increase size.
The library contain function's , dependecy needed by main program.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your answer, how does the forward deceleration affect overall size after linking

Comment: I just explained where used library and affecting size. I explained how  static and shared link work's and where is used.

Answer (score -4):

The lib file will always increase the size of the executable file, because you are executing a preprocessor with your application when you call a .h file.

Comment: You would include the same header file even if the implementation wasn't in a static library.

Comment: This explanation makes no sense at all. In half a sentence, it has the following errors: "preprocessor at runtime", "preprocesor counts towards executable size", ".h files are part of executable" and ".h files are called".